# Git. How can I temporarily switching back to a specific tag without truncating later commits

Tags: git

How can I change the version of a master temporarily to an older version without deleting any later commits. So, if I have

```
v.1.0 -> v.1.1 -> v.1.2 -> v.1.3
```

and I decide that I want to go back to v.1.1 temporarily without losing any of 1.2 or 1.3, how would I do that. I need the master to change, not just my local version.

Can I check out v.1.1 locally and commit and push it such that above chain would look like

```
v.1.0 -> v.1.1 -> v.1.2 -> v.1.3 -> v.1.1
```

and then simply later checkout v.1.3 and do the same to get into the state

```
v.1.0 -> v.1.1 -> v.1.2 -> v.1.3 -> v.1.1 -> v.1.3
```

?

For context, the reason why I am trying to do something like this is that I am looking for mechanics to switch back to an older version in case a bug appears. So, the thought was to revert to that older version until the bug is fixed. From some comments below, I assume a better solution would be to branch off v.1.1, point the master head to that branch and then drop that branch as soon as there is a fix and point back to the new version. So, as to go to

```
         v.1.1     <--- point master this branch
           ^
           |
v.1.0 -> v.1.1 -> v.1.2 -> v.1.3
```

and then

```
v.1.0 -> v.1.1 -> v.1.2 -> v.1.3 -> v.1.3.1
```

I thought this would be something that would be a very general procedure, so I expected there to be a fairly straightforward way to do that

Comment: it's not very clear for me what you want to achieve, but if you want to change the history of a remote, that's a bad ideea.

Comment: Without rewriting history you can check out v1.1, create a branch and commit and push. This would create a new branch that branches out from the commit referenced by v1.1, but it would not make v1.1 come after v1.3, it would just make a new branch, like parallel train tracks. Judging by your question I would urge you to go read up on how branches work in git, the days of a linear history is past, at least in the context of **that is the only solution**, git is much more branchy and parallel in nature, at least it allows you to be. You should understand how this works.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I edited to make things a bit clearer. will read up on branching and come back. ty